# how to apply a jquery code in angular directive

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I need insert a jquery code in a angular component, this jquery was in the html so not good practice.

I tried create a new function there and insert my jquery code , the jquery it is working very well, but i don't know why, the function link is now broken and not working.

I am new using angular and js so i can't understand well , can someone help to solve this? explain what is wrong in the code and i broken the function above

Thank you.

jquery code I tried to apply

```
  $('#close, #menu-toggle').click(function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          $('#wrapper').toggleClass('toggled');
        });
```

**angular file:**

```
 angular.module('test').directive('leftBar', [
      'leftBarService',
      function leftBar(leftBarService) {
        'use strict';

        var
          scope = {
            onLeafNode: '='
          };

        function link($scope, $element) {
          $element.leftBar({
            speed: 1000,
            useDynamicLoading: false,
            onLeafNodeReched: $scope.onLeafNode
          });

        }

        function menu ($scope, $element){
            $('#close, #menu-toggle').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#wrapper').toggleClass('toggled');
          });
        }

        return {
          restrict: 'A',
          scope: scope,
          link: link,
          link:menu,
          templateUrl: 'app/test/leftBar/leftBar.html'
        };
      }

    ]);
```

Comment: why you have got 2 link functions ? Other wise the code looks allright. what is the intention of your code. Do you want to run this piece of code every time the directive loads for the first time ?
Also, have you included the reference of JQuery ?

Comment: if I insert the piece of jquery code in the function link, works perfect, but I need create a function for menu and make both run. Understand?

Comment: write 2 function encapsulating the behaviour and call inside link. There can be only 1 link function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the returning object of the directive you are using two `link`s properties. You need to put the jQuery code you mention inside of the link function already declared and use just one `link` property in the returned object.

```
angular.module('test').directive('leftBar', [
  'leftBarService',
  function leftBar(leftBarService) {
    'use strict';

    var
      scope = {
        onLeafNode: '='
      };

    function link($scope, $element) {
      $element.leftBar({
        speed: 1000,
        useDynamicLoading: false,
        onLeafNodeReched: $scope.onLeafNode
      });

      menu();
    }

    function menu() {
      $('#close, #menu-toggle').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#wrapper').toggleClass('toggled');
      });
    }

    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      scope: scope,
      link: link,
      templateUrl: 'app/test/leftBar/leftBar.html'
    };
  }

]);
```

Comment: ok right there will work, but i need put this code in a function understand? I can't put inside the link function.

Comment: You can put it in a function, and call this function inside the link function. I update the code to show how to do this

Comment: thanks, just one thing menu sould be write in top on link right? how i will call menu if the fucntion is bellow? did load yet am i right?

Comment: Because of [var hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting) in JavaScript it does not matter in this case where you put the function declaration. More about [hoisting](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-hoisting-explained--net-15092). I recommend you using the [AngularJS Style Guide by John Papa](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide).

Answer (score 0):

When starting with angular , it is always better to leave your good practices in JQuery behind , because all that becomes a bad practice in angular and it is better to use an angular directive (somebody have written what you want already) than use JQuery within a directive  . For what you are trying to do you can refer the collapse directive in https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ .